# How to find out if systemd uses legacy, hybrid or unified mode (cgroupsv1 vs cgroupsv2)?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

Systemd can use one of three [modes](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/docs/CGROUP_DELEGATION.md#three-different-tree-setups-) in regard to how it manages cgroups:

- legacy
- hybrid
- unified

How can I check which one is it using?

Answer (score 16):

[According](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-November/041644.html) to Lennart Poettering:

> Try this:
>
> `stat -fc %T /sys/fs/cgroup/`
>
> if that reports "cgroups2fs" then you are in full cgroupsv2 mode. If
>   it returns "tmpfs" then you are in either full cgroupsv1 mode, or in
>   hybrid mode. Then, check if /sys/fs/cgroup/unified exists. If it does,
>   then you are in hybrid mode. if not you are in pure cgroupsv1 mode.

which translates to this shell code:

```
[ $(stat -fc %T /sys/fs/cgroup/) = "cgroup2fs" ] && echo "unified" || ( [ -e /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/ ] && echo "hybrid" || echo "legacy")
```